# Transforming the integral equation $u(x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|x - s|u(s)ds = ax + b$ into its equivalent differential equation

Tags: integral-equations

Let $u \in C^2[0, 1]$ satisfy for some $ \lambda \neq 0$ and $a \neq 0,$ $$u(x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|x - s|u(s)ds = ax + b.$$ Then show that u also satisfies $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \lambda u = 0$

I differentiate the integral equation twice w.r.t $x$. On first differentiation, I get
$$\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x - s}{|x - s|}u(s)ds = a$$

On second differentiation w.r.t., $x$, I get $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} = 0.$$

But how to do the prblem?

Comment: I provided 2 distinct approaches.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.   I just want to give you the best answer I can give you.

Comment: Your answer, I got it properly. But I am not able to find mistake in my approach @Dr.MV

Comment: I want to know that whether $\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x - s}{|x - s|}u(s)ds = a$ is correct. Secondly If I do like as follows: $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x - s}{|x - s|}u(s) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\del}{\del x} \frac{x - s}{|x - s|}u(s) = \int_{0}^{1}0. u(s) = 1$ then where does problem occur?

Comment: The problem is that $frac{d}{dx}|x|$ doesn't exist at $x=0$.  And $frac{d}{dx}\sgn(x)$ doesn't exist at $x=0$.  So, classically speaking, the interchange of operations is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

Let's split the integral into

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 |x-s|u(s)ds&=\int_0^x |x-s|u(s)ds+\int_x^1 |x-s|u(s)ds\\\\
&=\int_0^x (x-s)u(s) ds-\int_x^1 (x-s)u(s) ds
\end{align}$$

Now, differentiate using Leibnitz's Rule gives

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 |x-s|u(s)ds&=\left(\int_0^x \frac{d(x-s)}{dx}\,u(s)\, ds\,+(x-x)u(x)\right)\\\\
&+\left(-\int_x^1 \frac{d(x-s)}{dx}\,u(s)\, ds\,-(-1)(x-x)u(x)\right)\\\\
&=\int_0^x u(s) ds-\int_x^1 u(s) ds
\end{align}$$

A second application of Leibnitz's Rule (or here, simply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_0^1 |x-s|u(s)ds&=2u(x) 
\end{align}$$

Thus,

> $$u''+\lambda u=0.$$

---

**NOTE**:

A second way to carry out the analysis relies on use of the theory of generalized functions, and NOT classical analysis.  In this context,

$$\frac{d^2|x-s|}{dx^2}=2\delta(x-s)$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution (aka, the Dirac delta "function").  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\int_0^1 |x-s|u(s)ds&=\int_0^1\,\frac{d^2|x-s|}{dx^2}u(s)ds\\\\
&=\int_0^1\,2\delta(x-s)\,u(s)ds\\\\
&=2u(x)
\end{align}$$

as expected.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by a minute :)

Comment: thanx @Dr. MV.  Is $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} = 0$ incorrect?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!!!  And unfortunately, yes, it is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how you got $\int_x^1 |x-s|u(s)ds=-\int_x^1 (x-s)u(s)ds$ ? @Dr.MV

Comment: @quintic $|x-s|=-(x-s)$ when $x<s$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x-s}{|x-s|} = 2\delta(x - s)$$

Differentiating a second time should give
$$ \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_0^1 2\delta(x-s)u(s)\,ds = \lambda u(x) $$

Thus the equation is
$$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \lambda u = 0$$

Comment: This is the non-classical approach and relies on an understanding of the Generalized Function Theory.

Comment: I'm just using what I know, since I'm familiar with the delta function. But I like your answer too.

Comment: Sure, both are legitimate.  I provided both approaches.  But the classical approach is likely the one that others would have seen.