# $y(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-|x-t|)y(t)dt$ to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, integral-equations

> Convert $$y(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-|x-t|)y(t)dt$$ to differential equation with boundary conditions.

I know how to deal with this kind of problems but not when the kernel is a modulus function. I started solving it in the typical manner:

$$y'(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1  \frac{t-x}{|t-x|} y(t) dt.$$
It sort of rings the bell that $\frac{t-x}{|t-x|}$ could be $-1$ or $1$ depending on the values $x$ and $t$ on $[-1,1]$. Is there a way to determine those values? If I am right, it would be easy to solve this equation.

I also found another similar question ([Transforming the integral equation $u(x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{0}^{1}|x - s|u(s)ds = ax + b$ into its equivalent differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293034/transforming-the-integral-equation-ux-frac-lambda2-int-01x-su)) so I tried one of the methods in the answers:

$$\begin{align} \int_{-1}^1  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt = \int_{-1}^{-x}  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt + \int_{-x}^0  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt \\\\+ \int_{0}^x  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt + \int_{x}^1  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt
\end{align}$$

Then I'm really not sure what happens with the signs:

$$\begin{align} 
\int_{-1}^1  (1-|x-t|) y(t) dt = 
\int_{-1}^{-x}  (1+x-t) y(t) dt + 
\int_{-x}^0  (1-x+t) y(t) dt \\\\+ 
\int_{0}^x  (1-x+t) y(t) dt +
\int_{x}^1  (1+x-t) y(t) dt
\end{align}$$

Then by Leibnitz's Rule it should (?) follow that $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \int_{-1}^1 (1-|x-t|)u(t)dt=-4u(x)?$$ I feel like I just messed up with the signs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\le-1$, then
$$y(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-|x-t|)y(t)dt=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-(t-x))y(t)dt=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-t+x)y(t)dt$$
and hence
$$ y'(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 y(t)dt. $$
If $|x|<1$, then
$$y(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^x (1-|x-t|)y(t)dt+\lambda \int_x^1 (1-(t-x))y(t)dt=\lambda \int_{-1}^x(1-x+t)y(t)dt+\lambda \int_x^1 (1-t+x)y(t)dt $$
and hence
$$ y'(x)=\lambda y(x)-\lambda\int_{-1}^xy(t)dt-\lambda y(x)+\lambda\int_x^1y(t)dt=-\lambda\int_{-1}^xy(t)dt+\lambda\int_x^1y(t)dt. $$
So
$$ y''(x)=-2\lambda y(x). $$
If $x\ge1$, then
$$y(x)=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-(x-t))y(t)dt=\lambda \int_{-1}^1 (1-x+t)y(t)dt$$
and hence
$$ y'(x)=-\lambda \int_{-1}^1 y(t)dt. $$
Thus the equation is
$$ y''=-2\lambda y $$
with boundary condition
$$ y'(-1)=\lambda\int_{-1}^1y(t)dt, y'(1)=-\lambda\int_{-1}^1y(t)dt. $$